# Prove that $V_{m}:=\sum_{j=0}^{m}a_{j}T^{j}.\rightarrow f\left( T\right) $ in $B\left(X\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Let $f\left( z\right) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }a_{n}z^{n}$ be a
power series with complex coefficients and convergent on the open disk $%
D\left( 0,R\right) \subset \mathbb{C}$, $R>0.$

> If $T\in B\left(X\right)$ (i.e. $T$ is a bounded operator on a Banach space $X$)
>   with $\left\Vert T\right\Vert <R$. Why $V_{m}:=\sum_{j=0}^{m}a_{j}T^{j}.\rightarrow f\left(
> T\right) $ in $B\left(X\right)$ ?
>
> If $X$ is just a normed space not complete, is the above result remains true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that
$$||V_n-V_m||\leqslant \sum_{j=m+1}^n |a_j| ||T||^j$$
The RHS can be made arbitrary small, because $||T||$ is inside the radius of convergence of $f$. The completeness of $B(X)$ will guarentee that $(V_n)$ is convergent. But if $X$ is not Banach, then nothing will guarentee the completeness of $B(X)$.